# Sort list of ID by ID child in another node in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I building react-native chatroom feature by using Firebase. I would like to sort the chatList according to the lastMessage createdAt value in another collection.

Here is the sample structure of my current structure chat:

```
{
   Chatrooms: {
      CHAT_ID_1: {
         messages: [...],
         metadata: {
            lastMessages: {
                createdAt: 1515857717832  //the time
            },
            users: [USER_ID_1, USER_ID_2]
         }
      },
      CHAT_ID_2: {
         messages: [...],
         metadata: {
            lastMessages: {
                createdAt: 1515857717834  //the time
            },
            users: [USER_ID_1, USER_ID_3]
         }
      }
   },
   Users: {
      USER_ID_1: {
         chatList: {
            USER_ID_3: CHAT_ID_2,     
            USER_ID_2: CHAT_ID_1,
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Since the CHAT_ID_2 has the latest lastMessage createdAt time, it should be the first one in the chatList of USER_ID_1.

I would like to know how to sort this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see there is no way to do a query that gets you the chat rooms that a specific user is in order by last update timestamp.

Solutions I can quickly think of:

1. Load the last update timestamp for each room the user is in with a separate call, and then order them client-side.
2. Store the last update timestamp for each chat room for each user and then do a query.

I hope the first solution is self-explanatory. While it does require some extra code, it's actually a lot more efficient than most developers think because the [calls from the client to the database are pipelined over the same connection](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The second solution is to add additional data to `/Users/$uid/$chatroomid` to suit your use-case. So for example:

```
Users: {
  USER_ID_1: {
     chatList: {
        CHAT_ID_2: 1515857717834
        CHAT_ID_1: 1515857717832
     }
  }
}
```

With this structure you can get the chats in order of most recent update with:

```
firebase.database().ref("Users/USER_ID_1/chatList").orderByValue()
```

But in this case I'd go for option 1 myself. Since the number of chat rooms for each user is likely to be fairly small and the loads don't require queries, it's likely to both perform and scale well.